# how to understand GC Root by Monitor Used Object?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I want test for `Monitor Used` Object as GC root ,code just like as follow

```java
package cn.jast.jvm.gcroot;

/**
 * Monitor Used - objects used as a monitor for synchronization
 *
 * Created by jast90 on 2021/1/9
 */
public class GCRootMonitorUsed {
    BigClass bigClass = new BigClass();
    BigClass lock = new BigClass();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintMemoryUtil.printMemory();
        GCRootMonitorUsed gcRootMonitorUsed = new GCRootMonitorUsed();
        System.out.println("after create big class");
        PrintMemoryUtil.printMemory();
        System.gc();
        System.out.println("first gc");
        PrintMemoryUtil.printMemory();
        synchronized (gcRootMonitorUsed.lock){
            gcRootMonitorUsed = null;
            System.gc();
            System.out.println("second gc");
            PrintMemoryUtil.printMemory();
            System.gc();
            System.out.println("third gc");
            PrintMemoryUtil.printMemory();
        }
    }

    /*
    // move to a java file as not inner class
    class BigClass{
        private int _10MB = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
        private byte[] memory = new byte[8 * _10MB];
    }*/
}
```

```java
package cn.jast.jvm.gcroot;

/**
 * Created by jast90 on 2021/1/9
 */
public class PrintMemoryUtil {

    public static void printMemory(){
        System.out.println("free is :"+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024/1024 + "M");
        System.out.println("total is :"+Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()/1024/1024 + "M");
    }
}
```

and a result is:

```
free is :120M
total is :123M
after create big class
free is :40M
total is :203M
first gc
free is :42M
total is :203M
second gc
free is :42M
total is :203M
third gc
free is :42M
total is :203M
```

reference

- https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/gc_roots.jsp

Comment: The thread is holding a lock on a field of the instance, so perhaps it can't be collected. What happens without the synchronised block?

Comment: (although the garbage collector shouldn't care about what happens to the parent object... perhaps its just doesn't bother to collect that object as there is plenty of heap space)

Comment: > The thread is holding a lock on a field of the instance, so perhaps it can't be collected. What happens without the synchronised block?  That's what I'm testing.

Comment: Because there is no such thing as a null object. Unclear what you're really asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your own reference:

[image]

Assuming that reference is correct, I would interpret it as:

```
synchronized(obj) {
  // obj used as monitor
}
// obj free to collect
```

Answer (score 1):

Instances of the inner class `BigClass` have an implicit reference to the outer class `GCRootMonitorUsed`. As long as you keep a reference to a `BigClass` instance you also hold an implicit reference to the enclosing `GCRootMonitorUsed` instance.

Synchronizing on `gcRootMonitorUsed.lock` creates that strong reference to `gcRootMonitorUsed.lock` for the whole runtime of the synchronized block and therefore to the `GCRootMonitorUsed` instance.

The whole picture would change if `BigClass` were a static nested class that would not hold a reference to the outer class.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is a technical limitation, not a formal one. A synchronization is not required to have an effect when there is no subsequent synchronization by a different thread (and the class has not a `finalize()` method synchronizing on the object). The behavior might change when this method gets optimized by the JVM.